# keeping sdl2 and sdl1.2 on the same OS?

Tags: c++, linux, sdl, libraries, conflict

I installed SDL 1.2 long time ago with my package manager and now I have just installed from source the new SDL version (2.0).

Do you think it is safe to keep both version on the same OS? I need the old versions for other applications so I would prefer to have both..

PS I am on Linux.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be fine, I've already tried it for the same reason (I needed to use the older version, but I wanted to try the newer one) and it worked for me, just be sure to keep them in separate places and use one version at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You can let the SDL 1.2 and use the SDL 2.0 by loading in the execution (with LD_LIBRARY_PATH). Also, when compiling, you have to specify the include (-I)/library(-L) path of SDL 2.0